# Java Multithread Issue

Tags: java, multithreading

In the below code, my main task is not waiting for the sub task to complete its execution. I am new to Java Thread. So I could not able to fix it. I google it and found no luck. Please help me in fixing this thread issue. 
Code:

```
class ExecutorServiceManager{
public static ExecutorService getExecutor() {
    if (executorService == null) {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            if (executorService == null) {
                executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(150);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    if(executorService instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) executorService;
        int corePoolSize = threadPoolExecutor.getCorePoolSize();
        int maximumPoolSize = threadPoolExecutor.getMaximumPoolSize();
        Logger.info(ExecutorServiceManager.class, "ExecutorInfo: CorePoolSize:%s, MaxPoolSize:%s", corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize);
    }
    return executorService;
}}

class ServiceImpl{
ExecutorServiceManager executorServiceManager;
private void processConversion(String category, Map<String, String> couchDeltaMap, String processKey, String reqId) {
    try {
        ProgressVo progressVo = new ProgressVo();
        CountDownLatch pgCntxtcountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        executorServiceManager.getExecutor().submit(new MainTask(category, processKey, pgCntxtcountDownLatch, executorServiceManager, progressVo));
        Logger.info(ServiceImpl.class, "ExecutorInfo: CorePoolSize:%s, MaxPoolSize:%s", corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize);
        pgCntxtcountDownLatch.await();
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {} 
      catch(Exception ex) {}
}}

class MainTask implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {     
    executorService = executorServiceManager.getExecutor();
    executorService.submit(new SubTask(progressVo, couchDeltaMap, reqId, executorServiceManager));

    //I want the below operation to be executed, if and only the subtask completed its execution. 
    //But the below logger is printing before the subtask completed its execution.      
    Logger.info(MainTask.class, "It got executed before the subtask completed its processing");
    pgCntxtcountDownLatch.countDown();
}}

class SubTask implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {     
    executorService = executorServiceManager.getExecutor();
    doSomeProcess;
    //It stopped in the middle, and the Main task started executing the remaining operation
}}
```

Comment: Double-checked locking is broken unless you take certain steps, which aren't necessary because you shouldn't use double-checked locking anyway. Did you take the steps to make sure that the unnecessary double-checked locking idiom would work correctly?

Comment: If you are new to java threading I would stick to basic threading classes. It would force you to understand the mechanics then you can use classes that are easier to use if the mechanics are understood

Answer (score 0):

To get your main task to wait for the sub task execution, you could use the [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) returned by [Executor.submit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) this way:

```
class MainTask implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {     
    executorService = executorServiceManager.getExecutor();
    Future subTask = executorService.submit(new SubTask(progressVo, couchDeltaMap, reqId, executorServiceManager));
    try{
      subTask.get(); //wait for completion of the subtask
    } catch(Exception e){
         //You probably want better exception catching, this is just an example
    }

    Logger.info(MainTask.class, "It got executed before the subtask completed its processing");
    pgCntxtcountDownLatch.countDown();
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tried like what you have said. Please see the below code. Even with this code, I am not seeing the logger "Internal Thread Running Ends" message in my console.

Comment: I could not able to add the code in this comment box. Hence I put it in the answers section. Please refer that code. Even with this code, I am not seeing the logger "Internal Thread Running Ends" message in my console. Whereas I am seeing the MainTask logger, saying that it completed its processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainTask implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() { 
executorService = manager.getExecutor();
List<Future<Runnable>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Runnable>>();
while (!pageCntxts.isEmpty()) {
    popped = pageCntxts.pop();
    Future future = executorService.submit(new SubTask(progressVo, couchDeltaMap, reqId,manager));
    futures.add(future);
    if(pageCntxts.isEmpty())
        loadPageCntxtWithNext25Records(progressVo);
    processNum++;
}
Logger.debug(MainTask.class, "Internal Thread Running Starts with data size: "+futures.size());
for (Future<Runnable> future : futures) {
   future.get();
}
Logger.debug(MainTask.class, "Internal Thread Running Ends");}}
```